# Phonegap interent connectivity

Tags: android, cordova

I'm developing a jquery mobile app using phonegap build, I search on the web and I got a script on an alert which tells you are online. I've been working around the script with the intention of the alert only popping up when there's no internet but can't see to find my

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
// Wait for Cordova to load
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
// Cordova is ready
function onDeviceReady() {
        document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);

return false;
}

function onOffline() {
networkState = navigator.network.connection.type; 
if (networkState == Connection.NONE)
{
  alert('No internet connection ');
};
return false;
}
</script>
```

I've place the function in the body so it pops up

```
<body onLoad="onOffline()">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onLoad, false);
var Status = "";
```

**OR**

```
<body onLoad="onLoad()">

function onLoad() {       
  document.addEventListener("offline", offLine, false);
  document.addEventListener("online", onLine, false);
}

function offLine() { 
  alert("offLine");
  if(Status != 'disconnected') {
     Status = 'disconnected';
    // Your code
  }
}

function onLine() { 
   alert("onLine");
   if(Status != 'connected' && Status != '') {
     Status = 'connected';    
  }
}
```

Comment: so please which function should i place in the <body>? cos i can see three functions. and i can't find any alert there too

Comment: No need to put in body, simply put in your javascript file or inside <script></script> tag, bco'z  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onLoad, false); This event fires when Cordova is fully loaded.

Comment: nothing happens when the page loads, i'm testing with ripple emulator

Comment: check in device or android emulator