# Phonegap build network connection error

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm trying to check network is available or not in my android app.

My code

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.testback.build" version="1.0.2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
<icon src="assets/images/logo12.png" />
    <name>TestNetwork</name>
    <description>
        Desc for network check
    </description>

    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />

   <preference name="permissions" value="none"/>

   <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/> 
   <feature name="NetworkStatus">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.networkinformation.NetworkManager" />
   </feature>
</widget>
```

**In Js**

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() 
{
    checkConnection();   
}

function checkConnection() {
try{
    var networkState = navigator.connection && navigator.connection.type;
    alert(networkState); // returns undefined
    setTimeout(function(){
        networkState = navigator.connection && navigator.connection.type;

        var states = {};
        states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
        states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
        states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
        states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

        alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
    }, 500);
    }catch(e){
        alert(e);
    }
}
```

Is there any parameters to include in config file. I'm using phonegap 3.6.3

Comment: What kind of error you're seeing? Did you added the plugin properly? Added the cordova.js? Find the error in Eclipse logcat.

Comment: Yes, I added `cordova.js` file. network state returns undefined. 
`var networkState = navigator.connection && navigator.connection.type;`

Comment: can you try with this var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

Comment: @MohammedImranN Itried with this, It gives error `undefined type`

Comment: You can also check network connection like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28297854/phonegap-interent-connectivity/28298180#28298180